# How to summarize two data frames by matching date columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, merge, summary

I have two data frames: Original and Base......

```
Original<- data.frame(Bond = c("A","B","C","D"),Date = c("19-11-2021","19-11-2021","19-11-2021","17-11-2021"),
                  Rate =c("O_11","O_12","O_13","O_31"))
```

[image]

```
base<- data.frame(Date = c("19-11-2021","18-11-2021","17-11-2021"), Rate =c("B_1","B_2","B_3"))
```

[image]

Here I would like to calculate the rate differential between Original and Base for each bond of each date w.r.t. the base rate. The output should be in the following format -

[image]

***Note:*** **The original data frame contains numerical values of the Original and Base Rates**

I was trying using `group_by()` but wasn't able to proceed much further. Please help me with this. Even suggestion will also work

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to join on date, with dplyr you can with an inner_join, assuming that there exist a date in base for every record in Original:

```
Output <- Original %>%
  inner_join(base, by="Date") %>%
  mutate(Rate_Diff = paste0(Rate.x,"-",Rate.y), Rate=Rate.x) %>%
  select(-Rate.x, -Rate.y)

> Output
  Bond       Date Rate_Diff Rate
1    A 19-11-2021  O_11-B_1 O_11
2    B 19-11-2021  O_12-B_1 O_12
3    C 19-11-2021  O_13-B_1 O_13
4    D 17-11-2021  O_31-B_3 O_31
```

Edit: Is see the note now, then you could just replace the paste0 function with the actual columns:

```
 mutate(Rate_Diff = Rate.x - Rate.y, Rate=Rate.x)
```